# Can't get rid of Lycanthropy

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I maxed out my Werewolf perks and did all three Totem quests for Aela, so I wanted to get rid of my lycanthropy.

Simply going to Ysgramil with a Glenmoril's Witches head doesn't work, I can press the "Activate" button near the blue flames all I want, but it doesn't work. Several sources said that to be able to cure your own lycanthropy you had to start the quest "Purity" for either Vilkas or Farkas.

After a couple of radiant quests with two Witches' heads in my inventory Vilkas finally asked me to help him find a cure for his lycanthropy and he starts following me around for this quest. As soon as I leave Jorrvaskr, however, he says a random line and goes back inside. The quest is suddenly moved to my finished quests log, without it registering as either Completed or Failed...

I reloaded the autosave in Jorrvaskr and got the quest again, this time asking Vilkas to follow me. He said I already have a follower (which should be him) yet the quest was moved to my finished log again, this time without even leaving Jorrvaskr. Talking to Vilkas again led to him giving another radiant quest.

What else can I do?

Perhaps on a related note; Farkas won't give me any radiant quests whatsoever, so I can't cure him at all.

Comment: This sounds like more of an issue with Farkas than with the mechanics of getting rid of Lycanthropy. You're doing it right, he's just not cooperating.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Elder Scrolls Wikia Page on "Purity"](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Purity) this is a known bug.

```
     PC   360   PS3   After declining Vilkas's "Purity" quest, neither 
Farkas nor Aela have the option for any side quests in their dialogue 
― only the option to "Follow me." When attempting Vilkas's "Purity" 
quest, he leaves the Dragonborn as soon as they step outside of 
Jorrvaskr and the quest is moved to the 'Completed' list. Speaking to 
Vilkas again only offers the "Dragon Seekers" quest. When attempting 
to recruit a follower, characters will note that the Dragonborn 
already has someone with them when they do not. This bug is due to the 
"Purity" quest.
```

The only fix offered is to reload a save state to before you did the radiant quests or accepted "Purity" for the first time.

If you don't have a previous save state and really want to be cured of Lycanthropy there is another option, provided you have the "Dawnguard" add-on, which is to have Serana or Lord Harkon turn you into a vampire - which purges lycanthropy - and then have Falion of Morthal cure you of it. This route will require sacrificing a black soul gem however.